# Getting google oauth credentials without developer verification process

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm building an application in Python that downloads content of a Google spreadsheet from the drive of a user. Therefore the user has to authenticate in the Python app so that the app knows where and how to store the data and where to read it from.

One option is that I go through the developer verification process and then I provide my own client secret with the code. With that the application can receive a token and is registered. Unfortunately this is a security risk with publicly sharing my client secret.
Another option is that every user goes through the developer verification process on their own. But this is super cumbersome and takes lots of effort and time for every user.
Is there another simple and safe way of authentication?

Comment: You could probably use fastapi to proxy the request using your credentials on the server. You would still need a way in fastapi to manage access but you might find that easier to do.

Comment: you don't need to verify single user apps